# How to use parent function inside react's map function

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing the following functions to the following component...

```
<Main css={this.props.css} select={this.selectedCSS.bind(this)} save={this.saveCSS.bind(this)} />
```

Then inside the `Main` component I am using these functions...

```
<h1>Select the stylesheet you wish to clean</h1>
{
    this.props.css.map(function(style){

        if (style) {
            return (<div className="inputWrap"><input type="radio" name="style_name" onClick={this.props.select(style)}/><span></span><a key={style}>{style}</a></div>)
                }
            })
        }

        </div>
        <button className="cleanBtn" onClick={this.props.save}>Clean!</button>
```

Notice in my `map` function, I am passing `this.props.select(style)`. This is a function from the parent, and I am trying to pass to it a parameter. But when I do this, I get an error...

```
Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

Every other function I pass works. I've already tested them. In fact, the code works, the only issue is when I try to pass a function inside `map`. What is the reason for this? How can I fix it?

I tried to add `.bind(this)` but it runs in an infinite loop when I do so.

Comment: Have you tried to do `.bind(this)` for `function(style){}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) doesn't bind a `this` context unless explicitly told to.

```
this.props.css.map(function(style) {
  ...
}, this) // binding this explicitly
```

OR

```
this.props.css.map((style) => { // arrow function
  ...
})
```

OR

```
const self = this;
this.props.css.map((style) => {
  ... // access 'self.props.select'
})
```

---

I also see another problem with your code. Inside `map` you're doing this

```
if (style) {
    return (
        <div className="inputWrap">
            <input type="radio" name="style_name" onClick={this.props.select(style)}/>
            <span>something</span>
            <a key={style}>{style}</a>
        </div>
    );       
}
```

Here `input` element is expecting a function for its `onClick`, but you're actually evaluating the function by calling `this.props.select(style)` and passing its return value (if at all it returns something) to `onClick`. Instead you may need to do this:

```
this.props.css.map((style) => {
    if (style) {
        return (
            <div className="inputWrap">
                <input type="radio" name="style_name" onClick={() => this.props.select(style)}/>
                <span>something</span>
                <a key={style}>{style}</a>
            </div>
        );       
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your mapping function, `this` does no longer point to the react component.

**Bind the context manually** to resolve this:

```
{
    this.props.css.map((function(style) {
        if (style) {
            return (<div className="inputWrap"><input type="radio" name="style_name" onClick={this.props.select(style)}/><span></span><a key={style}>{style}</a></div>)
        }
    }).bind(this))
}
```

---

Alternatively, **use an ES6 arrow function**, which preserves the surrounding context:

```
{
    this.props.css.map(style => {
        if (style) {
            return (<div className="inputWrap"><input type="radio" name="style_name" onClick={this.props.select(style)}/><span></span><a key={style}>{style}</a></div>)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Ok this worked, but I have one more issue. My function `select={this.selectedCSS.bind(this, style)}` accepts a parameter. I am trying to pass it through the child as shown above but I keep getting an error. Whats the proper way to pass a parameter from child to parent?

Comment: @Bolboa - I offered a solution to the parameter passing in my answer

Comment: @Bolboa, I have updated my answer with a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned passing a parameter when calling a parent's function? As *onClick* wants a reference to a function (but realising that you need to pass a parameter), you could try the following:

```
onClick={() => { this.props.select(style) }}
```